# Can we Debug Xaml in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, debugging, xaml

Can we Debug Xaml in WPF? Is there any external tool or VS plugin which can do that?

Comment: It depends what you mean by, debug.  As Darin said it's a declarative language - it's not code that is run.  It's like asking to debug a HTML page: it's not code - the JavaScript is (in XAML's case that would be C# code-behind).  If you have a specific problem or error or something to 'debug', ask about that instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've occassionally found these tricks here useful...

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html

...particularly the second one where you use a dummy value converter to break in to the debugger.  It's useful for seeing exactly what objects are being bound, etc.

Comment: A similar post, Check this out for more elobrated details - http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52

Answer (score 21):

I don't agree with others that it's not possible to debug XAML, but it's true that there are no powerful tools available for this.

As Mark says in this post - http://markegilbert.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/debugging-xaml/

> So, the simple answer is yes, you can
> debug problems with XAML.  The longer,
> more qualified answer is that while
> it’s possible, the support isn’t
> terribly robust yet but should improve
> with newer dev environments (Visual
> Studio, Expression Blend, etc.).

Tips on how to debug and learn about WPF(Josh Smith):
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/29/tips-on-how-to-debug-and-learn-about-wpf/

[Wayback Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100731101640/http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Peter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=183) | [Get line numbers of XAML issues (Peter Himschoot)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100731101640/http://www.u2u.info:80/Blogs/Peter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=183):

> Simply add this to your project file:
>
> > ```
> > <!-- under the <PropertyGroup> tag -->
> > ```
>
> ```
> <XamlDebuggingInformation>true</XamlDebuggingInformation>
> ```
>
> > Now we at least get line number information on the problem :)

[More descriptive XAML exception details (Rob Relyea)](https://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2007/02/10/debugging-xaml-errors-at-runtime/)

[More on XamlParseException (Laurent Bugnion)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809032534/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx)

- > [image]

[Wayback Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100801080229/http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/ernow/archive/2006/02/22/3899.aspx) | [XAML Runtime Parsing Exceptions (c/o Erno de Weerd)](https://web.archive.org/web/20071107173733/http://blogs.infosupport.com:80/ernow/archive/2006/02/22/3899.aspx)

- > [image: Image of above blog]

[Wayback Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403043721/http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-debug-triggers-using-trigger.html) | [How to debug triggers using Trigger-Tracing(Dan Lamping)](http://ifigent.com/f.php?e=j2SPKAJhiIoH%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)

- > [image: Image of above blog]

[Debugging Dynamic XAML in Silverlight (Julia Lerman)](http://blogs.devsource.com/devlife/content/silverlight/debugging_dynamic_xaml_in_silverlight_1.html)

Just use google/StackOverflow to know how to debug specific XAML issues.

Comment: Debugging Data Bindings in a WPF or Silverlight Application -
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: 404 on Get line numbers of XAML issues (Peter Himschoot)

Comment: @mFeinstein Thanks. I have added the imp. info from that link to answer and a Wayback site link to access the cached post.

Comment: @LukášKoten Thanks for heads up. I updated few of them... will try to update others when I get some more time :)

Answer (score -4):

XAML is a declarative language and not imperative so I don't see how debugging it could be possible.

Comment: is there any external tool which can do that?

Answer (score -4):

No it is not possible.