# Trouble debugging WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, debugging

I made a small change to my wpf project and all of a sudden I got the below message.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

Additional information: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '7'.

This message didn't give me any idea what the really issue was. Luckily, I only made a small change.  I change a combo box to use an itemsource instead of adding the items and I didn't clear the values.

Bottom line is this the debugging didn't give me a clue to what happened. Is there anything that will help debugging these apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the painful world of WPF debugging.  Check out http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/04/02/110622.aspx for a way to make it hurt a little less.

Comment: thanks your help rob.  I like the idea of WPF.  But so far I am not impressed.  the debugging stinks.  Designing the UI can be a pain at times and doesnt always appear the same as in VS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

For some more useful links for debugging WPF application, you can have a look at my answer here - [Can we Debug Xaml in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155435/can-we-debug-xaml-in-wpf/3155764#3155764)

**Update:**

Tips on how to debug and learn about WPF(Josh Smith):
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/03/29/tips-on-how-to-debug-and-learn-about-wpf/

[Get line numbers of XAML issues (Peter Himschoot)](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Peter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=183)||[Wayback Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100731101640/http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Peter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=183):

> Simply add this to your project file:
>
> > ```
> > <!-- under the <PropertyGroup> tag -->
> > <XamlDebuggingInformation>true</XamlDebuggingInformation>
> > ```
> >
> > Now we at least get line number information on the problem :)

More descriptive XAML exception details (Rob Relyea):
http://rrelyea.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!167AD7A5AB58D5FE!1625.entry

More on XamlParseException (Laurent Bugnion): http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx

XAML Runtime Parsing Exceptions (c/o Erno de Weerd): http://blogs.infosupport.com/ernow/archive/2006/02/22/3899.aspx

“Debugging Dynamic XAML in Silverlight” (Julia Lerman): http://blogs.devsource.com/devlife/content/silverlight/debugging_dynamic_xaml_in_silverlight_1.html

How to debug triggers using Trigger-Tracing(Dan Lamping):
http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-debug-triggers-using-trigger.html

Just use google/StackOverflow to know how to debug specific XAML issues.